# NSTableview doubleAction but call action?

Tags: macos, nstableview

I'm writing an application for Mac. In NSTableview I set both handler for action and doubleAction.

```
self.tableView.doubleAction = #selector(tableViewDoubleAction)
self.tableView.action = #selector(tableViewSingleAction)
```

The problem is every double click the row in table view, it call both 'tableViewDoubleAction' and 'tableViewSingleAction'.
How can I separate it?
Thanks,

Comment: `NSTableView` inherits its action from `NSControl`. A single click selects a row. Do you want to change this?

Comment: Hi @Willeke, I want to separate the handler for single click and double click. Any way to do this?

Comment: See http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/288582-nstableview-action-doubleaction.html

Comment: Thank you. It's working @Willeke

Comment: @Willeke Can you update the linked answer or perhaps post it as answer? The link is dead so we don't know what the solution is.

Comment: [NSTableView action & doubleAction...](https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2010/Jun/msg00261.html) or [NSTableView action & doubleAction...](https://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg59131.html). Solution: wait in `tableViewSingleAction` for a second click or don't use `action` and observe selection changes.